# Infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is it possible to compute explicitly or in an approximate way the infinite series:

$$ S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k!} (a+k)^{-(n+1)}}$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 e^x x^{a-1} (\ln x)^n dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^1 x^{a+k-1} (\ln x)^n dx = n! (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a+k)^{-n-1}}{k!}$$ but I can't find it for any $x$

Comment: Actually, this series come from that integral. To get the $x$, you'll simply need to take $e^{x y}$ instead of $e^{x}$.

Comment: :) I was not so far. so you have to take the $n$th derivative of the incomplete gamma function, and to estimate the series there is not better than to approximate the integrand.

Comment: Writing it as $$S(x) = e^x \Bbb{E}[(X+a)^{-(n+1)}]$$ for $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(x)$ and applying some probability theory stuffs suggests that $S(x) \sim x^{-(n+1)} e^x$ as $x \to \infty$ with $a$ and $n$ fixed.

Comment: is it a joke ? at first you don't give the integral, and now you don't know that when $x \to 0$, $e^{x y} \to 1$

Answer (score 1):

hint for $a^{-(n+1)}(1+(\frac{k}{a}))^{-(n+1)}$ condition is $|k/a|<1$ so we can approximately take first $4,5$ terms according to significant figures and in $x^k$ we can treat $x$ as constant and it can be easily observed that after some terms $x^k/k!$ becomes small. But if we take k sufficiently large then it isnt possible.

Comment: You mean that the series $\sum_{k=n_0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k! k^{n+1}}}$ diverges?

Comment: Yes for small $k$,(moreorless depends on x)

Comment: I didn't understand quite well your comment, in which sense this depends on $x$?

Comment: If you keep $x$ as $1crore$ then wont you need many terms of $k!$ to over come the numerator number so it wont converge

Answer (score 1):

I found a closed formulation using [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials): $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}(a+k)^{-(n+1)}=a^{-(n+1)}xe^xT_{-n}(x)
$$
too bad there is no definition I found for Touchard polynomials with negative index.
Anyway you can maybe find useful the relation I found using negative binomial expansion: $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}(a+k)^{-(n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}\frac{x^k}{k!}\left (1+\frac{k}{a}\right )^{-(n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(n+1)}{j}\left (\frac{k}{a}\right )^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(n+1)}{j}\frac{1}{a^{n+j+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}{k}^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(n+1)}{j}\frac{1}{a^{n+j+1}}T_j(x)e^x
$$
If you have a way to evaluate rapidly the Touchard polynomials the factor inside the sum should decrease as $(x/a)^j$.